# Link from Django Model's "absolute url" to its admin page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url), you can specify a `get_absolute_url` in your Django Model for a "View on site" button to show up on Django Admin.

However, how would you do the opposite? A link on the above defined "absolute url" that takes you to the admin page for that instance? I can think of ways to hardcode the admin url and fill in just the instance ID, but I was hoping for a pythonic way (e.g. `instance.get_admin_url()`)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a description of named urls from admin which you can use in reverse() or in template url tag:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls